# Copying file from MTP device using libmtp (over USB)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, mtp

Have a current project where I'm trying to figure out a way to copy files(a video) from a [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) device over USB.

From the wiki I discover there is an open-source implementation called `libmtp`. Has anyone reading this used this? Any examples, tutorials?
I'd prefer to run Ubuntu with MATE.

Unix-like systems
A free and open-source implementation of the Media Transfer Protocol is available as `libmtp`.This library incorporates product and device IDs from many sources, and is commonly used in other software for MTP support.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Note, there is also a fuse filesystem [jmtpfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jmtpfs.1.html) which allows you simple access to the files. There may also be a [gnome plugin](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp) to handle mtp devices automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-dev mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Connect your device then run `mtp-detect`, this command will detect and give you some information about your device.

Run `mtp-connect` then `mtp-folders` to display your folders with their ID

the `mtp-files` will display your files/folders with their ID

to create a list file run:

```
mtp-files > file_list.txt
```

Use the command `mtp-getfile` to copy file from your device to your computer , there is an example from [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp#copy_files_off_your_smarphone_with_mtp-getfile):

> file_list.txt will now contain entries like this:

```
File ID: 81
Filename: WP_20161029_16_26_49_Pro.jpg
File size 936160 (0x00000000000E48E0) bytes
Parent ID: 12
Storage ID: 0x00010001
Filetype: JPEG file
```

> where "Parent ID" is something like the folder where the file resides on the smartphone. So you'll want to do something like this to get that particular file:

```
mkdir "12"
mtp-getfile "81" "12/WP_20161029_16_26_49_Pro.jpg"
```

Comment: My one remaining issue is how to reset the file ID since every time I delete the file the ID seems to increment by 1. I need the file ID to remain consistent

Comment: GAD3R THANKS!!! So even though Ubuntu natively supports mounting of MTP devices I assume I need these mtp libraries installed in order to issue these custom mtp commands for copying files. Am I correct?

Comment: @eco_bach correct , did you need an easy way to access your files using the file manager?

Comment: need to script series of commands to copy a single video file. One remaining issue, as mentioned, is  resetting the file ID after each copy and deletion