# Connect to Samsung Gear 360 as MTP device via command line?

Tags: usb, mtp

Using the following solution
[Copying file from MTP device using libmtp (over USB)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328665/copying-file-from-mtp-device-using-libmtp-over-usb) 
to access the videos on my Samsung gear 360 from a Linux(Ubuntu) desktop. 
I'm using the following MTP packages and have confirmed the Camera is recognized as an MTP device.

```
  sudo apt-get install libmtp-dev mtp-tools mtpfs
```

However when I try and connect via the following command

```
mtp-files > file_list.txt
```

I successfully create the text file but it only contains

> libmtp version: 1.1.10
>
> mtp-files: Successfully connected

and get the following command line errors

> Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
>   PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB
>   interface 
> LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device 
> LIBMTP PANIC: failed
>   to open session on second attempt Unable to open raw device 0

Anyone have any luck connecting to a Samsung Gear 360 from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your device. Create an udev-rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="disk", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Save it as `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules.` With upstart reload udev `sudo reload udev`, with systemd `sudo udevadm control -R`

if it not working can you write which ubuntu you have?

Comment: Thanks! Won't be able to test until Next Tuesday. Ubuntu-mate 16.04

Comment: ok lates Ubuntu-Mate. I discovered my code DOES work but I must first manually UN mount the device from the desktop. So my question becomes, how to un mount an MTP device from the command line?